# how to get the list of item with associated oldest value from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the 2 tables below:

```
table : Compte
IDcompte | Nom  | Prenom
--------------------------
1        | nom1 | prenom1
2        | nom2 | prenom2
3        | nom3 | prenom3
4        | nom4 | prenom4

table : Facture
IDfacture | valeur  | date       | IDcompte
--------------------------------------------
1         | 19      | 01/01/2019 | 3
2         | 15      | 04/01/2019 | 3
3         | 10      | 01/01/2019 | 2
4         | 13      | 09/01/2019 | 3
5         | 12      | 04/01/2019 | 1
6         | 10      | 06/01/2019 | 3
7         | 11      | 05/01/2019 | 2
```

I want to get the list of all account and for every compte I want the associated **latest** facture.
**How to use SQL to get this result ?**

```
IDcompte | Nom  | Prenom  | valeur  | date  
-------------------------------------------
1        | nom1 | prenom1 | 12      | 04/01/2019
2        | nom2 | prenom2 | 11      | 05/01/2019
3        | nom3 | prenom3 | 13      | 09/01/2019
4        | nom4 | prenom4 | null    | null
```

I tried this

```
Select *
FROM Compte
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT IDfacture, MAX(date) AS lastdate
    FROM Facture
    GROUP BY IDfacture) 
ON Compte.IDcompte = Facture.IDcompte
```

if someone have a good idea to deals with this trouble

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: sqlite 3 with python

Comment: I don't think anybody's mentioned yet that you need to change the format you're storing dates in to something like `YYYY-MM-DD` or julian date or something else that can be meaningfully sorted. `'04/01/2018'` compares as greater than `'01/01/2019'` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use left join and group by IDcompte

```
    Select *
    FROM Compte
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT Idcompte, MAX(date) AS lastdate
        FROM Facture
        GROUP BY Idcompte) c
    ON Compte.IDcompte = c.IDcompte
```

Comment: Why return this error "no such column: Facture.IDcompte". SQL request can't access to another underr request ?

Comment: ok i found the solution thanks to you. 'Select *
FROM Compte
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Facture.IDcompte, MAX(date) AS lastdate
    FROM Facture
    GROUP BY Facture.IDcompte) c
ON Compte.IDcompte = c.IDcompte'

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `LEFT JOIN` twice :

```
with cc as
(
select c.IDcompte, Nom, Prenom, max(date) max_date
  from Compte c
  left join Facture f 
    on f.IDCompte = c.IDCompte
 group by c.IDcompte, Nom, Prenom
)
select cc.IDcompte, Nom, Prenom, valeur, f.date
  from cc 
  left join Facture f on f.IDcompte = cc.IDcompte
   and f.date = max_date 
 order by cc.IDcompte;


idcompte    nom     prenom  valeur  date
1           nom1    prenom1 12      2019-01-04
2           nom2    prenom2 11      2019-01-05
3           nom3    prenom3 13      2019-01-09
4           nom4    prenom4
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mEdMzZBe8M6cZ9Bq8jRbfF/0)</kbd>

where `yyyy-mm-dd` is considered as the standard date format instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if sqllite supports this, but you can try.

If SQLlite has window functions, that would simplify it alot.

```
Select *
FROM Compte
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT F1.*
        FROM Facture F1
       INNER
        JOIN 
             (SELECT IDfacture, MAX(date) AS lastdate
                FROM Facture
               GROUP 
                  BY IDfacture
              HAVING date = MAX(date)
             ) F2
            ON F1.IDfacture = F2.IDfacture
  ) LatestFacture
ON Compte.IDcompte = LatestFacture.IDcompte
```

if it does have window functions you can do:

```
Select *
FROM Compte
INNER JOIN
    ( SELECT F1.*,
             RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY F1.IDFacture ORDER BY Date DESC ) rnk
        FROM Facture F1
    ) FACTURE_WITHRANK
  ON COMPTE.IDcompte = FACTURE_WITHRANK.IDcompte
 AND FACTURE_WITHRANK.rnk = 1
```

Comment: Only the first solution can be executed but looks the group by doesn't works

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted. I thought you wanted to get the latest value by IDfacture and join that back based on the IDcompte

Comment: Newer versions do have window functions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank all of us. I found the solution

```
Select *
FROM Compte
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT Facture.IDcompte, MAX(date) AS lastdate
    FROM Facture
    GROUP BY Facture.IDcompte) c
ON Compte.IDcompte = c.IDcompte
```